# Oracle stored procedure DB Link question

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dblink

I have a stored procedure `FOO` belonging to user `A`.  User `B` has `EXECUTE` permission on `FOO`.

One of the procedures in `FOO` uses a DB Link to retrieve data from `BARTABLE@REMOTEDB`.  `A` has a DB Link to `REMOTEDB` connecting as user `AREMOTE` while `B` has a DBLink with the same name connecting to `REMOTEDB` but as user `BREMOTE`.

When `B` executes `FOO`, will it use `A`'s DB Link (connecting as `AREMOTE`) or `B`'s DB Link (Connecting as `BREMOTE`)?

I ask because I assumed a procedure belonging to a particular user would only have access to that user's dblinks even if another user had `EXECUTE` on that procedure.  But somehow this procedure is working properly even though the user `AREMOTE` does not have `SELECT` on `BARTABLE@REMOTEDB`, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure should use the dblink that is defined for A's link. Any oracle procedure uses the rights of the owner to process, except where that procedure has been defined with "Invoker's Rights". [Invoker's Rights](http://www.dbasupport.com/oracle/ora9i/definer_invoker.shtml)

Invoker's rights defined for a procedure tells the code to use the rights and objects local to the calling user, and not the code owner. The reason that this is not done by default is typically an end user will have no rights to any hard objects for direct update, but be given proper access through an API, which would apply the correct business logic to updates, inserts and deletes, and then these objects would be exposed as accessible to the end user.